# Is it possible to achieve merged headers in Ag-Grid for React when working with two separate columns?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I wanted to achieve two headers merged for different columns using Ag-Grid in ReactJs, as both columns are editable and will have different custom renders.
Any idea how to achieve this with Ag-Grid in react?

[table to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9luu.png)

I was trying to achieve as in the above diagram

Comment: did you try the headerGroupComponent ?